# InternetExplorer.Application not supporting Document.Title only sometimes

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

This code is just to open IE read what page you are on and when you navigate to page copal inputs then navigate to page data services it will press back twice and refresh the page. I had it running fine from my desktop, but now when I run it from a short cut, will sometimes get an error that one of the lines with `IE.Documents.Title` "Object Doesn't Support this property or method."

I'm running this from a VBS file, but I also had the code working from Excel VBA.

```
Set objExplorer = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
Set objExplorer = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "WEBSITE"
IE.Visible = True
WScript.Sleep 2000
'On Error Resume Next
While IE.ReadyState <> 5 'I use 5 because I am pretty sure it doesn't exist.
  'DoEvents

  If Err.Number <> 0 Then WScript.Quit
    'WScript.Sleep 20

    If IE.LocationURL = "PAGE ON WEBSITE" Then
      IE.Goback
      IE.Goback
      IE.Refresh

      'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    End If

    If IE.Document.Title = "Copal Inputs" Then
      'This is sometimes supported, but sometimes not
      x = IE.Document.Title

      Cis = 1
      'MsgBox "DS"
    End If
    If IE.Document.Title = "Data Services" Then
      'This is sometimes supported then sometimes not
      If Cis = 1 Then
        IE.Goback
        IE.Goback
```

Comment: You need to wait until the DOM has loaded before you attempt to call it, it's likely not loaded when you attempt to check it. You should not try to read the `document` object until you have a `readyState = 4`.

Comment: Could I do that by just having my WScript.Sleep  longer or is there code for waiting specifically for DOM to be ready? Or is it just putting an if readystate = 4 before it tries doing things?

Comment: Blocking using `Sleep()` will be really inefficient and not guaranteed to work because how long the page takes to load is dependent on the latency / bandwidth of the connection. The better approach is to loop and only start checking once the DOM has loaded, you could do this by looping *(maybe adding a small `Sleep()` in to stop the script becoming unresponsive)* then checking `If IE.document.ReadyState = 4 Then` before accessing the DOM objects.